# Why won't regex match expected result

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract dates and event numbers from a section of a web page.  Here's the regex I'm trying to use: `Event \d+ begins (.+?) ((Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).+?) PST|PDT`

```
Event 4 begins for small business owners on Thursday, July 20, at 5:00 p.m. PDT in North America.
```

The key information I want here is the date for the correct event which in this case is `Thursday, July 20, at 5:00 p.m.`.

**What about this regex is causing it not to match this date?**  I've been through this several times and am not seeing it and need a second pair of eyes.

Here's a regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/oJyLld/3/

Comment: Try `Event \d+ begins (.+?) ((Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).+?) (PST|PDT)`
 The `OR - |` needs brackets for words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only major problem I found with your regex was at the end:

```
PST|PDT
```

Your pattern actually says to match the line of interest ending in `PST` or the isolated string `PDT`.  If you intend to match either `PST` or `PDT` the alternation should be wrapped in parenthesed as you did with the day abbreviations.  The following pattern seems to work:

```
Event \d+ begins (.+?) ((Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).+?) (PST|PDT)
```

Actually we can further improve upon the above:

```
Event \d+ begins (.+?) (?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).+? (?:PST|PDT)
```

This second version of your regex is an improvement because it does not capture the alternations (since you apparently do not need them).  This means that the regex engine might be able to match faster.  I also tried to unnest some of what your originally wrote.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for this, this is clearly the solution.  Can you elaborate on why the second regex is an improvement?

Comment: @Webnet I added an explanation.

Comment: Bingo, thanks!  That second regex also matched another variation of the text I was trying to match, whereas the first version didn't.

Comment: @Webnet can you tell us which text did the second version match and the first didn't? Because I'm under the impression that both will match the same text, just that the second version won't capture the text that you'll throw away eventually.

Comment: I ended up using `begins (.*)((?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).+?) (?:PST|PDT)` because it may just be "begins Thu....".

Comment: @Webnet Glad you have this issue resolved.  Let us know if you need more help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you look at https://regex101.com/r/U4bJWS/1 and see if you can determine why it's not stopping at the first match?